# getting different results for KNN using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, knn

I fitted the a model using K neareast neighbor algorithm using **knn function in class package** and **knn3 function in caret package**.

I used the `Smarket` data set in `ISLR` package.But for the same K value, (K=10) i am getting different results.

The results using the knn function as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
require(class)
require(caret)
str(Smarket)


trainx=Smarket[,-c(1,8,9)]
trainy=Smarket[,9]
set.seed(123)
knnm1=knn(trainx,trainx,trainy,k=10)
table(knnm1,trainy)

> table(knnm1,trainy)
      trainy
knnm1  Down  Up
  Down  352 206
  Up    250 442
```

The results using knn3 function as follows,

```
set.seed(123)
knnm2=knn3(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume,data=Smarket,k=10)
pred = predict(knnm2, Smarket, type = "class")
table(pred,Smarket[,9])

> table(pred,Smarket[,9])

pred   Down  Up
  Down  353 215
  Up    249 433
```

Since the results are different , i dont know which function gives the correct results.

Can anyone help me to identify why these 2 funstions give different results ?

Thank you

Comment: Interesting difference, what I have done several times is to contact the 'owner's or 'maintainers of the software(s) to find out if there are any differences in the way the calculations are done. Maybe try to show this difference to them to see if they realize that there is a difference. It looks like your model is ok but I do have one question. Why do you have "knn(trainx,trainx,trainy,k=10)" w/ 2 x trainx? Shouldn't you only need one?

Comment: @oaxacamatt That is  how it should write according to the syntax of knn function. The first trainx corresponds to the training data. The second trainx corresponds to the test data. In my model, i trained the model using trainx and after that predicted the outcome based on the trainx

Comment: Ok, I tried it and got the same as you... hmm, Have you talked to the Prof. or TA?

Comment: @oaxacamatt Thank you for checking. This is actually a self learning exercise .

Comment: We're all this in together. ;)